# Creating Express front end for node js backend API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm developing a platform which has school management I have already created every API in node js, Express and mongodb but now I don't know how should I make a front end in express coz when I was making stack app I'm using server side redering but in this case I have to use APIs and there is 5-6 API for every page how should I can securly do it in express front end coz lake of time I cant learn React or Angular right now. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,integrating express APIs with JQuery

https://grokonez.com/node-js/integrate-nodejs-express-jquery-ajax-post-get-bootstrap-view

Comment: This plugins are also for server side render I'm looking for something where I can use my APIs

Comment: Then you can try using plain html and try using ajax request and then deploy that html file using nginx. It should fulfil your purpose

Comment: Did it will show the API and other things in browsers debugger??

Comment: @geek This will show my APIs endpoint in debugger :(

Comment: Any with I can hide them

Answer (score 0):

Use templating engine like ejs. If you do not want to use frontend framework by this way you can use vanilla html and javascript to build application and have more control rather than consuming apis using jquery.

Comment: I used react js but now problem is my API calls are disclosed in network tab with secreat key